# What should be the Content-type header in this fetch API Javascript Code?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, asynchronous-javascript

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    "Content-type":
  },
  body: 'bar= foo& lorem=ipsum'

})
```

Should it be?

A) `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

B) `text/html; charset=utf-8`

C) `application/json; charset=UTF-8`

D) `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundry=something`

I've just started to learn JavaScript and APis. While looking at MDN docs I found there are different options to put in the headers. Just confused about which one to use?

Comment: Depends entirely upon what the server expects/cares about. urlencoded form data seems most appriopriate here based on the request body I think.

Comment: The body format `name=value&name=value` is Url-encoded.

Answer (score 2):

A sequence of `key=value` parameters separated by `&` is the URL-encoded format of parameters. So A is the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you! As a newbie, it's confusing sometimes. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

if you are sending url encoded data (**ex:** `key=value&key=value`) then `Content-Type` will be:

- A) **application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8**

if you are sending html data (**ex:** `<h1>hello</h1>`) then `Content-Type` will be:

- B) **text/html; charset=utf-8**

if you are sending json data (**ex:** `{"name" : "anyName"}`) then `Content-Type` will be:

- C) **application/json; charset=UTF-8**

if you are sending form data + files (**ex:** `new FormData(document.getElementById('form1'))`) then you don't need to set `Content-Type` manually that is:

- D) **multipart/form-data; boundry=something**